# Valid sample data for Directory API Explorer?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use the API Explorer on the Directory API to explore the required fields for the users.list method.

I am using the default OAuth and key.

This method requires a domain be passed and I'm not seeing in the documentation what the default domain is.

A closely related method, users.get, says that any user on the domain can use it to list basic information about another user (similar to the contacts.google.com behavior) on their domain, as long as they have the "key" for the user. The documentation does not appear to say whether the key is their email or another value.

I'd like to know what values I can enter in these fields in the Explorer to get data returned.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got something to work in Explorer, so here's what I know now.

- The domain is the domain you're signed into.
- The Key is a value that is in the basic information on users.

In addition to including the domain, I needed to specify my Projection ("Basic") and viewType ("domain_public"). I made sure that all the fields with drop-down menus had something selected.

At this point I was able to get a 200 response with users.